# Filtering withCount relationships with whereHas/whereIn doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am building a not-that-complex API with multiple related models but I can't seem to make the whereHas filter work as wanted.
So I have a structure like this :

```
Mapregions -> (hasMany) Subregions -> (hasMany) Countries
```

And below :

```
Groups -> (hasMany) Brands -> (hasMany) Units
```

Finally :

```
Unit -> (belongsTo) Country
```

I am trying to query all the Mapregions and have the count for each structure like this :

```
$mapregions = Mapregion::withCount(['groups', 'brands','units'])->orderBy('id');
```

This works great; but whenever I want to filter the units' country like this for instance :

```
$mapregions = $mapregions->whereHas('countries', function($query) use ($filterCountries){
    $query->WhereIn('countries.id', [2]);
});
```

I get a result where the Mapregion is retrieved correctly but the units count is the same as if there were no Countries filters; same goes for every 'count' and for every 'geo' filters.

I tried everything but I can't come up with a not-dirty-solution..
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "but the units count is the same as if there were no Countries filters"?

Comment: With or without the whereHas, the units count from the withCount is the same; and the same goes for every count from withCount (Wow you really are everywhere, opened an issue on your GitHub two days ago regarding HasDeep + Json  )

Comment: How should the `whereHas()` constraint influence the `withCount()` result?

Comment: Shouldn't the whereHas() filter out the results since in the models the units, brands, groups belongTo Country ?

Comment: `whereHas()` and `withCount()` don't influence each other at all. You need to add an additional constraint: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: I’ll try find where I got that from. So my only choice is to copy paste whereIn within every relations il withCount() that look sa so dirty. I did manage to get the results I wanted but it was not so elegant

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE : 
So for anyone looking for a solution; this *works*
It is ugly, but it works as intended.
First I filter out the results for the Mapregions level :

```
    $mapregions = $mapregions->WhereIn('id', $filterMap);
    $mapregions = $mapregions->whereHas('subregions', function($query) use ($filterSub){
        $query->WhereIn('id', $filterSub);
    });
    $mapregions = $mapregions->whereHas('countries', function($query) use ($filterCountries){
        $query->WhereIn('GEO_COUNTRIES.id', $filterCountries);
    });
```

Then I filter each withCount relation :

```
$mapregions->withCount(['groups' => function (Builder $query) use($filterMap, $filterSub, $filterCountries) {

    if (!empty($filterMap)){
        $query->whereIn('GEO_SUBREGIONS.mapregion_id', $filterMap);
    }

    if (!empty($filterSub)){
        $query->whereIn('GEO_COUNTRIES.subregion_id', $filterSub);
    }

    if (!empty($filterCountries)){
        $query->whereIn('GEO_COUNTRIES.id', $filterCountries);
    }

}, 'brands'=> function (Builder $query) use($filterMap, $filterSub, $filterCountries){
    if (!empty($filterMap)){
        $query->whereIn('GEO_SUBREGIONS.mapregion_id', $filterMap);
    }

    if (!empty($filterSub)){
        $query->whereIn('GEO_COUNTRIES.subregion_id', $filterSub);
    }

    if (!empty($filterCountries)){
        $query->whereIn('GEO_COUNTRIES.id', $filterCountries);
    }
},'units'=> function (Builder $query) use($filterMap, $filterSub, $filterCountries){
    if (!empty($filterMap)){
        $query->whereIn('GEO_SUBREGIONS.mapregion_id', $filterMap);
    }

    if (!empty($filterSub)){
        $query->whereIn('GEO_COUNTRIES.subregion_id', $filterSub);
    }

    if (!empty($filterCountries)){
        $query->whereIn('GEO_COUNTRIES.id', $filterCountries);
    }
}]);
```

It seems to work just fine.
If theres a way to clean the code to avoid duplicating the filters, I'd be glad to hear :)